# Deadlock from Range locks on primary key index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting weird deadlocks on a table (few tables, but they are all similar) and cannot make sense of it no matter how much I try to study Range locks. One process always only `SELECT` and is taking RangeS-U, then trying to convert it to RangeS-S. Why would Select take RangeS-U in first place? Other process does `UPDATE` and takes RangeX-X and tries to convert to X. Sometimes second process has X and tries to get X (or I am reading the graph incorrectly). Primary key index fields are never updated and there is no other index on table. The way business process goes, I can be certain that both select and update are working with records with big overlap. Can provide more information if required, table schema and deadlock graph is below.

**Table** -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeadlockTable] (
    [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL ,
    [Hour] [tinyint] NOT NULL ,
    [Status] [varchar] (32) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN NOT NULL ,
    [MW] [decimal](19, 6) NULL ,
    [CreationUserID] [int] NULL ,
    [CreationTime] [datetime] NULL ,
    [ModificationUserID] [int] NULL ,
    [ModificationTime] [datetime] NULL ,
    [SubmissionUserID] [int] NULL ,
    [SubmissionTime] [datetime] NULL ,
    [ConfigurationID] [varchar] (64) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_DeadlockTable] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID],
        [Hour]
    )  ON [PRIMARY] 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Deadlock XML** -

```
<deadlock-list>
    <deadlock victim="process5e13b88">
        <process-list>
            <process id="process5e13b88" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 22:72057594344112128 (6123af010c07)" waittime="2978" ownerId="265837907" transactionname="INSERT" lasttranstarted="2017-09-01T10:04:10.767" XDES="0x16fb323b0" lockMode="RangeS-S" schedulerid="2" kpid="5316" status="suspended" spid="83" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2017-09-01T10:04:10.430" lastbatchcompleted="2017-09-01T10:04:09.907" clientapp="..." hostname="..." hostpid="7980" loginname="..." isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="265837907" currentdb="22" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="adhoc" line="40" stmtstart="3776" stmtend="7404" sqlhandle="0x020000009555563118dcb9a28a078c9faa795d95341a9119">
                        INSERT INTO #TempTable (
                        ...
                        )
                        SELECT DISTINCT
                        ...
                        FROM Table1 B
                        LEFT JOIN DeadlockTable P ON B.[ID] = {more joins, got cropped}
                    </frame>
                    <frame procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_executesql" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0400ff7fbe80662601000000000000000000000000000000">
                        sp_executesql
                    </frame>
                    <frame procname="EXEC SPROC" line="386" stmtstart="28814" stmtend="29462" sqlhandle="0x03001600afff210aad8d3f01d0a700000100000000000000">
                        EXEC sp_executesql ...
                    </frame>
                    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x010016009a0b8926e0fb577e010000000000000000000000">
                        EXEC SPROC ...
                    </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>
                    EXEC SPROC ...
                </inputbuf>
            </process>
            <process id="process5e45b88" taskpriority="0" logused="236" waitresource="KEY: 22:72057594344112128 (55ed2fdeaf5a)" waittime="3130" ownerId="265839001" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2017-09-01T10:04:14.840" XDES="0x484c171b0" lockMode="X" schedulerid="7" kpid="4852" status="suspended" spid="90" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2017-09-01T10:04:14.817" lastbatchcompleted="2017-09-01T10:04:11.883" clientapp="..." hostname="..." hostpid="7980" loginname="..." isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="265839001" currentdb="22" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="EXEC SPROC2" line="141" stmtstart="9324" stmtend="10424" sqlhandle="0x03001600a8150d4e1c673f01d0a700000100000000000000">
                        UPDATE BP
                        SET BP.[Status] = CASE @Cancel WHEN 1 THEN &apos;Voided&apos; ELSE &apos;Submitted&apos; END, BP.[MW] = CASE @Cancel WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE BP.[MW] END, BP.[SubmissionUserID] = @SubmissionUserID, BP.[SubmissionTime] = @SubmissionTime
                        FROM #FinalResult FR
                        CROSS JOIN Hour25 H25
                        INNER JOIN DeadLockTable  BP ON BP.[ID] = FR.[ID] AND BP.[Hour] = H25.[HE]
                        INNER JOIN fnc_List2Table(@HourList, &apos;,&apos;) HL ON H25.[HE] = HL.[Value] OR @HourList = &apos;0&apos;
                        WHERE (FR.[MarketType] = 1 OR (FR.[MarketType] = 2 AND BP.[Hour] = FR.[Hour]))
                    </frame>
                    <frame procname="adhoc" line="2" stmtstart="18" sqlhandle="0x010016002c9cbb0aa05380f3000000000000000000000000">
                        EXEC SPROC2
                    </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>
                    EXEC SPROC2
                </inputbuf>
            </process>
        </process-list>
        <resource-list>
            <keylock hobtid="72057594344112128" dbid="22" objectname="DealockTable" indexname="PK_DealockTable" id="lock451ea9e80" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594344112128">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process5e45b88" mode="X"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process5e13b88" mode="RangeS-S" requestType="wait"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </keylock>
            <keylock hobtid="72057594344112128" dbid="22" objectname="DealockTable" indexname="PK_DealockTable" id="lock109ed6380" mode="RangeS-U" associatedObjectId="72057594344112128">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process5e13b88" mode="RangeS-S"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process5e45b88" mode="X" requestType="convert"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </keylock>
        </resource-list>
    </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

**Deadlock Graph**
[image: deadlock graph from sql trace]

Comment: Do you need to run the select query in `serializable` transactional isolation? That may be contributing to why your select query is trying to obtain higher level locks

Comment: @Xedni this is a financial application so serializable is pretty much unavoidable for us. I'll cross post to dba.stackexchange too, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Just something to consider, because that's going to contribute to locking and hamstring your options a bit. You could consider using `sp_getapplock` in both processes (which behaves a lot more like an `lock` in something like C#). That would prevent at least whichever procedures you added that to trying to lock the same things you put inside the applock'd body. Something like Snapshot isolation might be someting to look into as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's classic deadlock when one process(victim) reads on `serializable` level and another updates the same clustered table.

You are confused with what is converted to what.

The first process ("process5e13b88") has acquired `RangeS-S` lock and waits for another `RangS-S` lock (where there is `X` lock of update process), it converts nothing.

The second "process5e45b88" has acquired `X` lock on one key and `U` on another key and wants to convert it to `X` but it cannot because there is `RangeS-S` lock.

I attach the picture where you can see that one process wants and acquires only `RangeS-S` locks and another only `X` locks.

When you see `RangeS-U` lock this means there is `RangeS-S` lock on the range but the key itself has `U` lock

[image]

Comment: Can you suggest a solution to it? I do not want to do dirty reads and I cannot reliably reproduce the issue to test any kind of locking hints that might improve the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a nonclustered index on your deadlock table using the join columns as key columns and the returned (i.e. columns in the SELECT section) columns as included columns.

Read [Using a Clustered Index to Solve a SQL Server Deadlock Issue](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2517/using-a-clustered-index-to-solve-a-sql-server-deadlock-issue/) for further explanation.  I know the title doesn't sound like what I'm telling you to do, but the article shows how a nonclustered index can be used to resolve deadlock issues.